# Does a good framework for MongoDB "schema" upgrades in Scala exist?

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift, nosql

What are the options for MongoDB schema migrations/upgrades?

We (my colleagues and I) have a somewhat large (~100 million record) MongoDB collection. This collection is mapped (ORM'd) to a Scala lift-mongodb object that has been through a number of different iterations. We've got all sorts of code in there which handles missing fields, renames, removals, migrations, etc.

As much as the whole "schema-less" thing can be nice and flexible, in this case it's causing a lot of code clutter as our object continues to evolve. Continuing down this "flexible object" path is simply not sustainable.

How have you guys implemented schema migrations/upgrades in MongoDB with Scala? Does a framework for this exist? I know that Foursquare uses Scala with MongoDB and Rogue (their own query DSL)... does anyone know how they handle their migrations?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are storing that has 100 million records.. purely curious... I love to see where/how technology is used

Comment: @AdamGent: global coverage of stock corporate action data (dividends and splits), going back for quite a while. Next up might be tick-history with 1-second-ish resolution... that's _way_ more data, and a whole different can of worms.

Comment: We do data migration with fairly straightforward (versioned) JavaScript scripts and a schema version document in a reserved collection to automatically trigger the appropriate migrations.

Comment: <nitpick>technically, MongoDB<->object mapping is not Object **Relational** Mapping</nitpick> :P

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this can help somewhat, this is how Guardian.co.uk handle this:

http://qconlondon.com/dl/qcon-london-2011/slides/MatthewWall_WhyIChoseMongoDBForGuardianCoUk.pdf

Schema upgrades

This can be mitigated by:

- Adding a “version” key to each document
- Updating the version each time the application modiﬁes a document
- Using MapReduce capability to forcibly migrate documents from older versions if required

Comment: the external link is not valid any more, but thanks that you mentioned the main points here

Answer (score 2):

I program migrations of MongoDB data with my own Scala framework ["Subset"](http://github.com/osinka/subset). It lets define document fields pretty easily, fine tune data serialization (e.g. write "date" is a specific format and so on) and build queries and update modifiers in terms of the defined fields. This ["gist"](https://gist.github.com/1647302) gives a good introduction